# Algorithm to find all minimal dependent subsets in a finite set of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Is there a fast algorithm to find all minimal dependent subsets in a finite set of vectors? One slow algorithm is to check each subset of the given set and to see if it is minimal dependent. I would like to know a fast algorithm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really need *all* minimal dependent subsets? (In an $n$-dimensional space, you can have as much as $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\asymp2^n/\sqrt{n\pi/2}$ of these; even just enumeration can be considered "slow".)

Comment: @metamorphy, yes, I need to find all minimal dependent subsets.